# textView not display output

Tags: android, if-statement, textview

I'm building apps that detect color when 'imageview' is clicked. Unfortunately, after I get rid all the warning at 'getResource().getContent()',the output did not display. or my 'if'  is wrong? perhaps someone can help me :)

```
Button button;
ImageView imageView;
static final int CAM_REQUEST = 1;
TextView  colorRGB;
Context context = this;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.capimg);



    colorRGB = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.colorrgb);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);



    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Intent camera_intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File file = getFile();
            camera_intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
            startActivityForResult(camera_intent, CAM_REQUEST);





        }
    });






    imageView.setOnTouchListener(imgSourceOnTouchListener);
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

    String path = "sdcard/UTP_app/cam_image.jpg";
    imageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(path));

}



private File getFile() {
    File folder = new File("sdcard/UTP_app");
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        folder.mkdir();
    }

    File image_file = new File(folder,"cam_image.jpg");
    return image_file;
    //return new File(folder, new Date().getTime()+".jpg");
}


OnTouchListener imgSourceOnTouchListener
        = new OnTouchListener(){

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {



        int blue1 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Blue1);
        int blue2 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Blue2);
        int blue3 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Blue3);
        int blue4 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Blue4);
        int blue5 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Blue5);
        int blue6 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Blue6);
        int blue7 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Blue7);
        int blue8 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Blue8);
        int blue9 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Blue9);
        int blue10 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Blue10);
        int blue11 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Blue11);
        int blue12 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Blue12);
        int blue13 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Blue13);
        int blue14 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Blue14);
        int blue15 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Blue15);
        int blue16 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Blue16);
        int blue17 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Blue17);
        int blue18 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Blue18);
        int blue19 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Blue19);
        int blue20 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Blue20);
        int blue21 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Blue21);
        int blue22 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Blue22);
        int blue23 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Blue23);
        int blue24 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Blue24);
        int blue25 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Blue25);

        int green1 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Green1);
        int green2 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Green2);
        int green3 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Green3);
        int green4 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Green4);
        int green5 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Green5);
        int green6 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Green6);
        int green7 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Green7);
        int green8 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Green8);
        int green9 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Green9);
        int green10 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Green10);
        int green11 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Green11);
        int green12 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Green12);
        int green13 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Green13);
        int green14 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Green14);
        int green15 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Green15);
        int green16 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Green16);
        int green17 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Green17);
        int green18 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Green18);
        int green19 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Green19);
        int green20 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Green20);


        int white1 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.White1);
        int white2 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.White2);
        int white3 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.White3);
        int white4 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.White4);
        int white5 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.White5);
        int white6 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.White6);
        int white7 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.White7);
        int white8 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.White8);


        int brown1 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Browns1);
        int brown2 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Browns2);
        int brown3 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Browns3);
        int brown4 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Browns4);
        int brown5 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Browns5);
        int brown6 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Browns6);
        int brown7 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Browns7);
        int brown8 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Browns8);
        int brown9 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Browns9);
        int brown10 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Browns10);
        int brown11 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Browns11);
        int brown12 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Browns12);
        int brown13 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Browns13);


        int orange1 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Orange1);
        int orange2 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Orange2);
        int orange3 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Orange3);
        int orange4 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Orange4);
        int orange5 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Orange5);
        int orange6 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Orange6);
        int orange7 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Orange7);
        int orange8 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Orange8);
        int orange9 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Orange9);
        int orange10 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Orange10);







        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();
        float[] eventXY = new float[] {eventX, eventY};

        Matrix invertMatrix = new Matrix();
        ((ImageView)view).getImageMatrix().invert(invertMatrix);

        invertMatrix.mapPoints(eventXY);
        int x = 0;
        int y = 1;



        Drawable imgDrawable = ((ImageView)view).getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imgDrawable).getBitmap();


        //Limit x, y range within bitmap
        if(x < 0){
            x = 0;
        }else if(x > bitmap.getWidth()-1){
            x = bitmap.getWidth()-1;
        }

        if(y < 0){
            y = 0;
        }else if(y > bitmap.getHeight()-1){
            y = bitmap.getHeight()-1;
        }

        int touchedRGB = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);








        //colour for blue
        if (touchedRGB == blue1)
        {
            //colorRGB.setText(R.string.blue_colour);
            colorRGB.setText("Blue");
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == blue2)
        {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.blue_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == blue3)
        {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.blue_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == blue4)
        {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.blue_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == blue5)
        {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.blue_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == blue6)
        {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.blue_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == blue7)
        {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.blue_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == blue8)
        {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.blue_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == blue9)
        {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.blue_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == blue10)
        {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.blue_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == blue11)
        {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.blue_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == blue12)
        {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.blue_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == blue13)
        {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.blue_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == blue14)
        {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.blue_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == blue15)
        {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.blue_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == blue16)
        {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.blue_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == blue17)
        {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.blue_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == blue18)
        {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.blue_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == blue19)
        {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.blue_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == blue20)
        {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.blue_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == blue21)
        {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.blue_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == blue22)
        {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.blue_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == blue23)
        {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.blue_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == blue24)
        {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.blue_colour);
        }
        else if(touchedRGB == blue25)
        {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.blue_colour);
        }


        //color for white


        else if (touchedRGB == white1) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.white_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == white2) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.white_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == white3) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.white_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == white4) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.white_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == white5) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.white_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == white6) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.white_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == white7) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.white_colour);
        }
        else if(touchedRGB == white8 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.white_colour);
        }

        //colour for green

        else if (touchedRGB == green1 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.green_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == green2 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.green_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == green3 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.green_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == green4 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.green_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == green5 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.green_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == green6 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.green_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == green7 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.green_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == green8 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.green_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == green9 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.green_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == green10 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.green_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == green11 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.green_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == green12 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.green_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == green13 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.green_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == green14 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.green_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == green15 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.green_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == green16 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.green_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == green17 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.green_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == green18 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.green_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == green19 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.green_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == green20 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.green_colour);
        }

        //colour for brown

        else if (touchedRGB == brown1 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.brown_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == brown2 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.brown_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == brown3 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.brown_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == brown4 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.brown_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == brown5 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.brown_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == brown6 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.brown_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == brown7 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.brown_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == brown8 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.brown_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == brown9 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.brown_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == brown10 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.brown_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == brown11 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.brown_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == brown12 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.brown_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == brown13 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.brown_colour);
        }


        //colour for orange and
        else if (touchedRGB == orange1 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.orange_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == orange2 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.orange_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == orange3 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.orange_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == orange4 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.orange_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == orange5 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.orange_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == orange6 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.orange_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == orange7 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.orange_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == orange8 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.orange_colour);

        }
        else if (touchedRGB == orange9 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.orange_colour);
        }
        else if (touchedRGB == orange10 ) {
            colorRGB.setText(R.string.orange_colour);
        }






        return true;
    }};

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    DJ.iAmLeaving();

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    DJ.iAmIn(this);
}
```

here is '.xml'

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.zaidi.frame2.MainActivity2"
android:background="@drawable/background3"
android:orientation="vertical">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Capture"
    android:textSize="55sp"
    android:id="@+id/CreditButton"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Capture Image"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/CreditButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:id="@+id/image_view"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/colorrgb"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#ebcaca" />
```

and lastly my 'color.xml'

```
<color name = "White1">#ffffff</color>
<color name = "White2">#f0ffff</color>
<color name = "White3">#f0f8ff</color>
<color name = "White4">#e6e6fa</color>
<color name = "White5">#fff0f5</color>
<color name = "White6">#f5fffa</color>
<color name = "White7">#eeeee0</color>
<color name = "White8">#eee8dc</color>



<color name = "Green1">#7fffd4</color>
<color name = "Green2">#66cdaa</color>
<color name = "Green3">#006400</color>
<color name = "Green4">#556b2f</color>
<color name = "Green5">#8fbc8f</color>
<color name = "Green6">#2e8b57</color>
<color name = "Green7">#3cb371</color>
<color name = "Green8">#20b2aa</color>
<color name = "Green9">#98fb98</color>
<color name = "Green10">#00ff7f</color>
<color name = "Green11">#7cfc00</color>
<color name = "Green12">#7fff00</color>
<color name = "Green13">#00fa9a</color>
<color name = "Green14">#adff2f</color>
<color name = "Green15">#32cd32</color>
<color name = "Green16">#9acd32</color>
<color name = "Green17">#228b22</color>
<color name = "Green18">#6b8e23</color>
<color name = "Green19">#bdb76b</color>
<color name = "Green20">#f0e68c</color>


<color name = "Blue1">#191970</color>
<color name = "Blue2">#000080</color>
<color name = "Blue3">#6495ed</color>
<color name = "Blue4">#483d8b</color>
<color name = "Blue5">#6a5acd</color>
<color name = "Blue6">#7b68ee</color>
<color name = "Blue7">#8470ff</color>
<color name = "Blue8">#0000cd</color>
<color name = "Blue9">#4169e1</color>
<color name = "Blue10">#0000ff</color>
<color name = "Blue11">#1e90ff</color>
<color name = "Blue12">#00bfff</color>
<color name = "Blue13">#87ceeb</color>
<color name = "Blue14">#87cefa</color>
<color name = "Blue15">#4682b4</color>
<color name = "Blue16">#b0c4de</color>
<color name = "Blue17">#add8e6</color>
<color name = "Blue18">#b0e0e6</color>
<color name = "Blue19">#afeeee</color>
<color name = "Blue20">#00ced1</color>
<color name = "Blue21">#48d1cc</color>
<color name = "Blue22">#40e0d0</color>
<color name = "Blue23">#00ffff</color>
<color name = "Blue24">#e0ffff</color>
<color name = "Blue25">#5f9ea0</color>




<color name = "Browns1">#bc8f8f</color>
<color name = "Browns2">#cd5c5c</color>
<color name = "Browns3">#8b4513</color>
<color name = "Browns4">#a0522d</color>
<color name = "Browns5">#cd853f</color>
<color name = "Browns6">#deb887</color>
<color name = "Browns7">#f5f5dc</color>
<color name = "Browns8">#f5deb3</color>
<color name = "Browns9">#f4a460</color>
<color name = "Browns10">#d2b48c</color>
<color name = "Browns11">#d2691e</color>
<color name = "Browns12">#b22222</color>
<color name = "Browns13">#a52a2a</color>



<color name = "Orange1">#e9967a</color>
<color name = "Orange2">#fa8072</color>
<color name = "Orange3">#ffa07a</color>
<color name = "Orange4">#ffa500</color>
<color name = "Orange5">#ff8c00</color>
<color name = "Orange6">#ff7f50</color>
<color name = "Orange7">#f08080</color>
<color name = "Orange8">#ff6347</color>
<color name = "Orange9">#ff4500</color>
<color name = "Orange10">#ff0000</color>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're setting text for your `rgb TextView` from `string.xml` so you should change

```
colorRGB.setText(R.string.blue_colour);
```

to

```
colorRGB.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.blue_colour));
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Definitely yes ! You are using `If` wrongly, You are initializing value of `x`

```
int x = 0;
```

**And checking**

```
if(x < 0)
```

**Which always returns false.**

Comment: should I initialize x as 1? sorry i'm newbie

Comment: changed but still have the same problem

Comment: There may be other kind of problem too, You have to find out them... And don't use neither `0` nor `1`  use `if(x < bitmap.getWidth()-1)`. As your statements.

Comment: Change your statements too as **Phan Văn Linh** answered.